# JS function that smooth scrolls to an element after pageload referred by an anchor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

For the last few days I am working on an automated smooth scroll function in JS that scrolls to a div container (the container should be centered in the screen, not like the CSS smooth behavior).

I found dozens of solutions but not one of them worked in my case..

What I have is a little dropdown-menu that contains references to divs on the page of the parent.
The User should be able to click on any of those links and then get directed to the same page but with a different scrolling event..

e.g. If he clicks on "Damen" in the dropdown-menu, the page "Leistungen" is supposed to load followed by an event that smooth scrolls to the given element. What I do not want is the standard CSS smooth scroll.

Sadly I am just learning Javascript and can only alter given solutions so much, sadly it just never ever worked..

If it helps heres the full Code in my CodePen: https://codepen.io/gisbert12843/pen/NWrRjbE

For a live view visit: https://gisbertstestsite.xyz/dist/htmls/leistungen.html

And heres a bit of my current Code (just the relevant parts) ^^

The navigation:

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/index.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li class="active dropdown"><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html"><i class="fas fa-cut"></i>
                Leistungen</a>
            <div class="dropdown-class">
                <ul class="dropdown-content">
                    <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html#Herren">Herren</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html#Damen">Damen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html#Jugend_Kinder">Jugend und Kinder</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html">Farben und Strähnen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html">Wellen und Glätten</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html">Extension | Perücken | Toupets</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html">Kuren</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html">Brautservice</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/dist/htmls/leistungen.html">Kosmetik</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

An example div element it should scroll to:

```
<div class="blurwrapper Herren" id="scroll-Herren">
       <div class="table">
              <table class="fl-table"></table>
       </div>
</div>
```

And my current (not working) javascript

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        let page_url = window.location.href;
        let page_id = page_url.substring(page_url.lastIndexOf("#") + 1);
        // alert(page_id);
        if (page_id == "Jugend_Kinder") {
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: $("#scroll-" + page_id).offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }

    });
</script>
```

I am thankful and open to any kind of hints and suggestions, no matter how small!

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Everyone has to start from somewhere right? ^^

I feel the problem is although you do the URLs correctly you haven't specified your anchors IDs. Though the URL is asking for `/dist/htmls/leistungen.html#Herren` there is no element with the ID "Herren".

Each anchor `a-url-link-and#someAnchor` will look for an element with id `#someAnchor`

Also please be aware that:

- Anchor links and ids are case sensitive
- When a new page loads and there is already an anchor id specified (I think) the browser would automatically scroll.